# Matrix operation

Tags: matrices, physics

The below [calculation](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/01/17/spin-statistical-calculations/) is  finding the  expectation value of Pauli Matrix.  I understood the physics how they got the below term but, I don't get that how the final result  is zero in the  equation . $\displaystyle \langle S_{x}\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{50}(\begin{array}{cc} -3i & 4)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 3i\\ 4 \end{array}\right)=0\end{array} \ \ \ \ \ $

After doing matrix operation, I obtain different answer.

Comment: Check your calculations, the answer is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the matrix times the last vector:
$(\begin{array}{cc} -3i & 4)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 3i\\ 4 \end{array}\right)=\end{array} (\begin{array}{cc} -3i & 4)\left(\begin{array}{c} 4\\ 3i \end{array}\right)=\end{array} 0$